# Taking one file as input, removing its contents from other file

Tags: bash

As part of a script I am writing I need to take a file (list of words) as input and remove all instances of those words from the other input file. How would I do something like this? Maybe using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$ grep -v -f words_to_exclude.txt input.txt
```

where

`-f` specifies the file of words you want grep to match on

`-v` specifies that you want grep to output what *doesn't* match

The above requires one word per line in both files.

Comment: better consider to grep with `-F` and `-w`

Comment: This would remove entire lines containing the matched words, not just the words themselves.

Answer (score 1):

**man grep** says this:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>                Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

and this:

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

So, yes, using grep would be a good way. At least if you want to remove *all lines containing special words* from the input file. If you only want to remove the individual words, things get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

sed is probably what you're looking for. Example script:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
for word in $(cat $1); 
do
sed s/$word//g $2 > tmp;
mv tmp $2;
done;
```

Assuming you saved this into script.sh, you would call it like this:

```
./script.sh wordsToExclude.txt textToProcess.txt
```

`$1` is "argument number 1" in bash in this case `wordsToExclude.txt`, similarly, `$2` is `textToProcess.txt`

What this does is that it replaces every instance of $word with nothing, the tmpfile is there just as a buffer for sed to write in so that it would not destroy the source while working.

The `g` in the sed command is the "global replace flag". The default behavior for sed is to only replace the first occurrence of the search pattern in a line. The `g` flag tells sed to replace all occurrences and not just the first.

Comment: This only addresses half the problem; there is an entire file full of words to be removed from the other file, not just a single word stored in a variable.

Comment: @chepner Rectified. I assumed he was looking for that "part" of the answer at first and not the rest. Which could still be true, but I edited the answer anyway.